Setting up a new Next.js app with Craft
I'm having trouble fetching data in a new Next.js app from Craft.

I'm on Next 15.0.3 and Craft 5.5.

I've got CRAFT_CMS_GRAPHQL_TOKEN and CRAFT_CMS_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT set up in my .env file.

I've got 'api' => 'graphql/api' in routes.php.

I've created my schema in Craft and have tested it with graphiql.

I've got a fetchApi.tsx that looks like this:
export async function fetchData(graphql) {
let craftUrl = process.env.CRAFT_CMS_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT;

const res = await fetch(craftUrl, {
  method: 'post',
  body: graphql,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/graphql',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.CRAFT_CMS_GRAPHQL_TOKEN}`
  },
});

if (res.status !== 200) {
  throw new Error('Failed to fetch API');
}

const json = await res.json();

if (json.errors) {
  console.error(json.errors);
  throw new Error('Failed to fetch API');
}

return json.data;

}


and then in page.tsx I have
import { fetchData } from "./utils/fetchApi";

async function getContent() {
  const data = await fetchData(`
    {
      entries(section: "content") {
        id
        ... on content_Entry {
          id
          title
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  return data.content;
}

export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const content = await getContent();

  console.log(content);
}

With that I get

[ Server ] Error: fetch failed

pointing at const res = await fetch(craftUrl….
Some Googling suggested using localhost or 127.0.0.1 instead of my dev URL and I've tried both of those but get the same result.
I can hit my API URL in a browser and it returns a message:

No GraphQL query was supplied

so it seems that it's only a problem accessing it from within Next. Anyone got any advice on what's missing from my set-up?

It turns out it was a problem with UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE, i.e. self-signed certificates. The solution was to update the dev script in package.json to "dev": "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 next dev".
